# Code that works in Broadcast Receiver doesn't work in Activity

Tags: java, android, screen-orientation

The following code runs in a BroadcastReceiver and adds a transparent overlay to the system-level window manager to keep the orientation in Landscape mode. This code works fine.

When I put this code in an Activity, however, to have the Activity add the overlay instead, nothing happens. For the life of me, I cannot figure out why. I have it in a method that gets called from an OnClickListener. I know the method gets called because of a Toast message I put at the top of the method.

```
        final View view = new View(context);
        int dimension = 0;
        int pixelFormat = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;

        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                dimension, dimension,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                pixelFormat);
        params.screenOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
        final WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.addView(view, params);
```

What is wrong with this code that won't let it run in an activity?

In the activity, every instance of `context` is replaced with `this`. Could this be the issue?

Comment: I assume that this code is in the onReceive() method that you override? If so, are you actually sending a broadcast via sendBroadcast(Intent intent) ?

Comment: This is code taken from a BroadcastReceiver (which works fine and is not the issue here) and put into an onClickListener in an activity (which does not work and is the issue here)

Comment: in that case, if this is an Anonymous class and you are trying to reference context, try YourActivityName.this.getActivity().

Comment: you don't need the getACtivity() part. The Activity Itself is the context.

Comment: I have changed `this` to `StartNXRotation.this` (my Activity name) and now something happens, but not what I want. Now when I go to my homescreen I get just a blank screen with my wallpaper (apparently still in Portrait mode). I want to see what I would normally see, but forced into landscape mode.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may very well lay in your Context.

Turns out that the context in the `onReceive` method in the Broadcast receiver it not the same `context` as the Activity. It will inflate UI elements, but inflation will be done with the default theme for the system on which you are running, not what’s defined in your application. (You have to be aware of this in case this becomes a problem).

On the other hand, when you are inside an onClickListener, is this onClickListener Anonymous or a hard reference?

E.g.: Are you doing

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() { //code }; );
```

Comment: The onClickListener is attached to a button.

    startButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() { //code }; );

Comment: Well that part was to tell you to do YourActivity.this ;)

Comment: Now the other problem may have nothing to do with the Activity/Broadcast but the view you're trying to add/modify.

Comment: Why do you think that is? The View and params are the same in both the BroadcastReceiver and the activity. Copied and pasted. It works fine in the Receiver

Comment: I'm not sure, it's hard to see without more "context" (no pun intended). What are you exactly trying to do ? Lock the orientation? When is this Broadcast receiver being called? by whom? THere are a lot of questions :)